# How to package a hidden folder inside the root of a WAR file, using SBT?

Tags: sbt, lift, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to build a WAR file (containing a Lift project) suitable for deployment to Elastic Beanstalk. I also need to configure my application using [`.ebextensions`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers.html).

`.ebextensions` should be stored in the root of a WAR file. Where should resources be placed so they end up in the root of a WAR file in SBT `package`? Using `src/main/resources` appears to place resources in `WEB-INF/classes`.

Even when I place the `.ebextensions` folder in, say, my src/main/resources folder and `package` the WAR file, the folder doesn't appear (in `WEB-INF/classes`). If I remove the leading period then it does appear. So how can SBT also be configured to package hidden folders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place the folder in src/main/webapp.

**Update 10/23**
As Richard Dallaway pointed out below, this no longer seems to work and there is a good explanation by SBT's author of why here: [How to make SBT to not-ignore .ebextensions folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19054135/how-to-make-sbt-to-not-ignore-ebextensions-folder).  The short answer is to add this:

```
excludeFilter := HiddenFileFilter -- ".ebextensions" //or whatever your hidden folder name is
```

To your build.sbt file.

Comment: Didn't work for me with SBT 0.12.2. I used `jar uf target/scala-2.10/blah-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.war src/main/webapp/.ebextensions` to insert the dir into the WAR file after packaging.

Comment: It seems to also need to instruct xsbt-web plugin to not exclude the file.  This is described by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19054135/how-to-make-sbt-to-not-ignore-ebextensions-folder

Comment: doesn't work in sbt version 0.13.6...had to update jar after sbt package