# How to make SBT to not-ignore .ebextensions folder?

Tags: sbt, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a webapp that is built via SBT and is deployed into Amazon Elastic Beanstalk. In order to configure Beanstalk instance, one needs to put `.ebextensions` folder with config files into root of WAR file. However, putting this folder into `src/main/webapp` doesn't help, because SBT by default ignores all hidden folders, so resulting WAR doesn't contain the folder.

Is there some way to configure SBT to include this folder into the build, besides it's hidden? Or how can I put this folder into the build some other way? I'm using jenkins to automate build and deploy so unpack - add folder - pack again isn't really an option, unless it can be somehow scripted. Thanks!

Comment: How are you making your war file?  A plugin?

Comment: Yes, via Jenkins SBT plugin (v1.3). But also if I do `sbt package`, resulting WAR is also missing this folder. Both Jenkins and my devel machine use sbt 0.12.3

Comment: The jenkins sbt plugin just runs sbt.  What plugin or task is actually generating the war file?

Comment: Sorry, I've misunderstood your question. I'm using xsbt-web-plugin and `package` task to generate war file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The web plugin appears to respect `excludeFilter`, which is by default:

```
excludeFilter := HiddenFileFilter
```

You can redefine it to allow `.ebextensions`:

```
excludeFilter := HiddenFileFilter -- ".ebextensions"
```