# HOWTO include a resources folder after decompressing in maven, before packaging the final WAR file

Tags: maven, amazon-web-services, maven-plugin, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

**BACKGROUND**

In order to work with new approach of customizing AWS's Elastic Beanstalk Using Configuration Files I need to supply YAML config files in a `.ebextensions` folder and place it at the root of the WAR file structure and then deploy it to tomcat.

I really want to avoid putting config files in the source code repository since it has commands that are specific to OS on which the web application is being deployed. And I feel that these config files should not be coupled with source code of the web apps.

**PROBLEM**

Now the problem is I need to fetch this config files, including the `.ebextensions` somehow & then place them in the root just before maven created the final WAR file, ready to be deployed.

Since I need to maintain the directory structure of putting config files in a specific folder, I can only make available a zip file, which then needs to be decompressed & then put in the root of the WAR file by maven.

My question is that is there a way to automate this via maven or I need to take a different approach for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a shell script which executed before the build job was run. It was as follows,

```
# This set of of commands will fetch the EC2 customization commands from S3 & package it inside the WAR file which will be then deployed to the server.
pwd
ls -la
# Create "temp" directory to put the fetched configs in to.
mkdir -p temp
ls -la temp/
rm -rf temp/*
cd temp
# Fetch the configs
s3cmd sync -vrf s3://tanzchantz.cdn/resources/configuration/ebs/customize-webapps-container/ .
tree -afphug .
# Copy the configs in to webapp directory
cp -rv . ../webapps-main/src/main/webapp/
cd ..
ls -la webapps-main/src/main/webapp/
```

Answer (score 2):

This helped me: http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-beanstalk-maven-plugin/example-ebextensions.html

You can also try this: [How to package a hidden folder inside the root of a WAR file, using SBT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14751665/how-to-package-a-hidden-folder-inside-the-root-of-a-war-file-using-sbt)